# AES MDS D-XOR and S-XOR count

Tags: aes, xor, mds

I am trying to implement the D-XOR and S-XOR count in python but despite reading multiple articles on how to perform the calculation I have failed to understand the process used. I would appreciate it if someone could demonstrate the process using an example. Below I have included some of the references that detail the process.

GF(256)

```
MDS=[[2, 3, 1, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 3],
    [3, 1, 1, 2]]
```

[image]

```
Generator Coefficients=100011011
Generator Polynomial = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x^1 + 1
```

references:

> https://tosc.iacr.org/index.php/ToSC/article/view/806/760
> https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/422.pdf
> https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/422.pdf
> https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8409223
> https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1084.pdf
> https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1090.pdf

Comment: That MDS matrix looks wrong; it should have 4 4's, not only 2 of them.  And, no MDS matrix has a 2x2 submatrix of only 1's

Comment: @poncho you were right about the 2x2 submatrix of 1's. I reviewed my code and noticed that the sliding window mechanism had a step size of 2 which would cause issues when filtering out invalid MDS matrices. Thank you for your comment!!!